# Dynamic initialization of Bean - Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, microservices

I am having trouble finding a good solution for creating beans which initialization must be delayed.
My situation is that I have to delay creation of beans so my microservice can launch and create them after the launch has finished - for curious ones I am using vertX verticle as Microservice.

So far I am solving it by annotating launch dependent beans by @Lazy and calling them after successful launch with getBean method.

e.g. - passing eventBus as argument which can be created only after successful launch of microservice since it is needed for this bean.

`(CrudRepository<Installation>) ctx.getBean("installationCrudRepository", eventBus);`

I also have to delay initialization of all beans dependent to the lazy ones by also annotating them with @Lazy and call them later with getBean which is not a good looking solution.
This approach works but it is definetely not a good design and intellIj does not like it either.

I could not find a solution to this problem, perhaps there is a way to manually create a Bean and make the others initialize once it is supplied?

Best regards,
Michael

Comment: Why are your beans dependent of a running microsevice? Your microservice should have an event that it fires when it si ready so you can listen and to post-startup logic.

Comment: @cdalxndr and that's how it is. I have a post start-up logic after microservice is launched - and that's only when I can get things live vertx instance or EventBus used to communicate with other microservices. I need them for my Beans.

Comment: I think there is a design issue.I don't know Vertx, but I imagine, if you create a Vertx service bean that will contain all those dependencies available after microservice startup, then at Vertx ready event, you call some init method on the VertxService and it populates all required dependencies. Of course, until Vertx fires ready event and you init the service, VertxService should fail any client requests (public methods), or you can return some Future objects that will complete after init.

Comment: Doesn''t Vertx have some manual initialization method? You can call it inside your VertxService bean initialization to set all your Vertx dependencies, and use VertxService as an entry point for all Vertx related operations.

Comment: I am launching microservices from Docker. After launch has succeeded    
```@Override
    public void init(Vertx vertx, Context context) {}```
method is called and here I get all the needed dependencies - in vertx instance is all what I need. I cannot init it manually since I need the very same instance of vertx to communicate with other microservices.
The question is, can I somehow pass it to @Configuration class?

Comment: @Veidt, require more details. Understood Vertx initialization should happen first. But how are you initializing Spring? Why cant you to initialize Spring context manually after initialization of Vertx?